# seaborn boxplots at desired distances along the x axis

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

Is there anyway to place `seaborn` boxplots at desired distances along the x axis?

I've got a dataframe with 
    hierarchical column index with indices  Assignment, Max, Type
    a row index of student names

```
+------------+----------+---------+----------+---------------+
| Type       | Homework | Quiz    | Homework | Presentations |
|            | max 100  | max 100 | max 100  | max 100       |
+------------+----------+---------+----------+---------------+
| Assignment | 1        | 2       | 3        | 4             |
+------------+----------+---------+----------+---------------+
| Student 1  | 88       | 98      | 100      | 85            |
+------------+----------+---------+----------+---------------+
| Student 2  | 96       | 79      | 100      | 97            |
+------------+----------+---------+----------+---------------+
| Student 3  | 87       | 79      | 72       | 78            |
+------------+----------+---------+----------+---------------+
| Student 4  | 87       | 84      | 90       | 85            |
+------------+----------+---------+----------+---------------+
| Student 5  | 73       | 91      | 76       | 90            |
+------------+----------+---------+----------+---------------+
| Student 6  | 70       | 75      | 98       | 82            |
+------------+----------+---------+----------+---------------+
| Student 7  | 85       | 71      | 73       | 75            |
+------------+----------+---------+----------+---------------+
| Student 8  | 76       | 81      | 94       | 86            |
+------------+----------+---------+----------+---------------+
| Student 9  | 97       | 80      | 95       | 88            |
+------------+----------+---------+----------+---------------+
```

In reality the Assignments are strings and more descriptive.

I can easily feed the dataframe into seaborn and it will produce a nice box plot
sns.boxplot(df)

What I'd really like is for the boxes to be separated onto different subplots (not hard), but to be spaced properly chronologically.

More clearly:

Currently `sns.boxplot(df)` places all the box plots chronologically which is nice.
I'd like a subplot above it, for example, which had only the quiz box plots, but the quiz box plots are lined up horizontally on the x axis with where they would fall if all the assignments were included.

Is there anyway **to place seaborn boxplots at desired distances along the x axis**?

`sns.boxplot(df['Quiz'], x=[1,5,9,12])`    DOES NOT work as you can't override the x 'values' (but these are just the labels).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=np.repeat([0, 3, 5, 6], 10),
                       y=np.random.randn(40)))
sns.boxplot(x="x", y="y", data=df, order=np.arange(7))
```

[image]

Comment: this is cool for integer positions but not practical for float positions. Any suggestions how to achieve that?

Comment: @jlarsch One just can't do it with a regular boxplot, because the x axis is always categorical. The thing in this answer is just a trick, in that sense, that works with integers.

Answer (score 7):

**UPDATE**: It seems, I was wrong, as [mwaskom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1533576/mwaskom) pointed out, you can specify positions by cleverly using `order` keyword, but it seems you would need to reshape your data from 'wide' to 'long' format.

---

The short answer is *no*, `seaborn.boxplot` does not have an option to specify the position of the boxplots along the x axis.

If you don't care much for the style or can specify it manually, you can use `pandas.DataFrame.boxplot` instead, which has `positions` property.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy.random as rnd   # just to generate some data

data = pd.DataFrame(rnd.randn(10,4))
data.boxplot(positions=[1,5,6,10])
plt.grid('off')
```

[image: boxplot with positions]